# Why $P(A|B)\neq P(B|A)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In my study of conditional probability, it is given that $$P(A|B)\neq P(B|A),$$ where $A$ and $B$ are  two arbitrary events. I was wondering, why is this true? It may seem trivial and counter-examples are easy to produce, but I am hoping for some intuition.

Comment: In general these are not the same,  but in some cases they might be...

Comment: Why should the fraction of A's that are B's be the same as the fraction of B's that are A's?  Replace "A" and "B" by any nouns such that it is possible to be both A and B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\mathbb P(A\mid B)=\mathbb P(B\mid A)$ is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(B)}=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(A)},
$$
which is equivalent to $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(B)$ (assuming that $\mathbb P(A\cap B)>0$), and arbitrary events won't usually satisfy $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(B)$.

Now for the intuitive explanation. Think about what $\mathbb P(A\mid B)$ means, in terms of a Venn diagram: you are shrinking the probability space down to just the set $B$, and looking to see what proportion of $A$ still falls inside that, but it is *relative to the whole size of $B$*. If it wasn't for the "relative" part, then it wouldn't matter if you started with $B$ and shrunk $A$ down, or started with $A$ and shrunk $B$ down. But since conditional probabilities are relative, it matters if the space you are "shrinking down to" is $A$ or if it is $B$, since that determines what quantity you are dividing by in the conditional probability.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Quick question: where does Bayes' theorem fit into this idea? Does Bayes' theorem allow us to reverse the direction of the conditional probabilities?

Comment: Bayes' theorem says that when you "undo" the shrinking, you get back to something symmetric: $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(B\cap A)$. If you replace $\mathbb P(A\cap B)$ with $\mathbb P(A\mid B)\cdot \mathbb P(B)$ and likewise for the right side, you get Bayes' theorem which allows you to express one of the conditional probabilities in terms of the other.

Comment: But this does not imply that $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\mathbb{P})B|A)$?

Comment: No, because you have a $\mathbb P(B)$ on the left and a $\mathbb P(A)$ on the right, and those two don't cancel each other out.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\equiv \mathbb{P}(A|B)\mathbb{P}(B)$?

Comment: Yes... so $\mathbb P(A\mid B)\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(B\mid A)\mathbb P(A)$.

Comment: Awesome. So in general $\mathbb{P}(A|B)\not\equiv\mathbb{P}(B|A)$, but Bayes' theorem describes how the two are related?